# calendar package usage

Tags: calendar, dtx

I've been trying to use an old calendar package downloaded from here:
https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/calendar?lang=en
and now I'm not sure how to use it. I've installed it and was able to compile several demo files (e.g. demowkly.tex).
As far as I understand one edits his calendar events inside caldemos.dtx file, but how should I run it? Compiling with pdflatex and latex gives no output, compiling with just tex gives an error about ltxdoc documentclass.
Any guidance will be appreciated (I'm using Miktex 2.9 on Windows, if it helps)

Comment: the installation instructions are in the readme start by running tex on `allcal.ins` which will extract all the needed files http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/calendar/README

Comment: I did followed the instructions and installed this file (successfully I believe). The question is how to proceed afterwards.